# Does Less css uses cache

Tags: less

I need to know if less uses by default some kind of cache for the compiled css in the browser when am using the less.js inclution way.
Maybe localstorage?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does

Use this to clear it on page load. Put it just after you include your less file, but before your js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (typeof localStorage != "undefined") for(i in localStorage) if (i.indexOf('.less') != -1) delete localStorage[i];
</script>
```

**note**: this should only be used for development purposes, you don't want to be delivering and parsing less every time the page loads for your end users. That will cause unnecessary strain on your servers. compile beforehand and link in the resulting css file.